# How can hermitian matrix have orthornormal eigen vectors with same eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices

Suppose hermitian matrix has same eigen values

There is a thereom saying that every hermitian matrix has is similar to siagonal matrix.

If hermitian matrix has same eigen values, it seems to me that eigenvectors corresponding to same eigenvalues are not indpendent and therefore not orthononrmal.

Comment: Look at the $2 \times 2$ identity. The standard basis vectors $e_1$ and $e_2$ are both eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $1$. And they are not only independent, but orthonormal.

Comment: You know that for different eigenvalues the eigenvectors are orthonormal ( and hence linearly independent ). It does not mean that for equal eigenvalues the eigenvectors are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 2):

The eigen vectors are not defined uniquely for such case. But they can be chosen orthonormal.